# sudo apt update Received 11 errors. Don’t know what to do

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, sudo, bashrc

When I wrote sudo apt update I received 11 different errors. I took a **screenshot** could someone help me fix this. I’m extremely new to Linux bash commands. I just took a 5hour class on the “50 most common Linux Commands” so I thought I’d try a few out. I only screwed up my laptop. **PLEASE HELP**[Screenshot of errors received.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhlwS.jpg)

Comment: The screenshot is unreadable. Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

Comment: Your attached pictures show (*if I'm reading correctly*) that you're not using Ubuntu anyway, thus are off-topic here (Linux Mint is Ubuntu based, and not a Ubuntu system, nor Ubuntu *flavor* that is on-topic here). You look like you have network issues (or at least DNS issues)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I honestly didn’t know that Linux Mint is not part of Ubuntu so that you for clearing that up.

Comment: FYI:  All Ubuntu systems have *Ubuntu* in the name (eg. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours where they're Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE, Ubuntu-Budgie, Ubuntu-Kylin, Ubuntu-Studio, Ubuntu... etc) & all are downloaded from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ etc... being created by Ubuntu tools on launchpad etc... Ubuntu-based will come from elsewhere, and are different (eg. Ubuntu systems don't use runtime *adjustments* etc that Linux Mint does, as Ubuntu has upload rights to its own repositories (Linux Mint can't amend Ubuntu packages, but relies on them thus runtime adjustments etc)